# Open Source Objective-C Math/Calculator engine

Tags: objective-c, math, calculator

Hej guys,

I was wondering if you know any well working Math or Calculation engines written in Objective-C? Found a graphing one using CorePlot already....
Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You can already use your favourite C library in your Objective-C program; what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I´m looking for an engine solving mathematical equatations or at least an engine who can display technical mathematical expressions like "7/8*4) into a format that I can display to the user (like real fraction lines and all that stuff or exponential expressions and so on and so on....) is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get some use out of David Stes' CAKit (a computer algebra package), but you'll have a ton of hacking to do, since Stes is ravingly anti-FoundationKit and wrote the whole thing based on the old, pre-NeXT ICPak API. (Don't go looking to him for help -- you'll get a world of hurt.)

The key issue to keep in mind is that ICPak was based on Smalltalk and describes more or less the intended function of the class, while FoundationKit class names tend to describe the raw functionality itself; the most useful correlation will probably be OrdCltn -> NSMutableArray; you'll also have to tweak the memory management to use autorelease. It's not impossible, but you do have to understand the philosophy that FoundationKit follows.